# Kendo UI grid export excel and pdf export, no file created

Tags: javascript, ajax, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying to create a kendo grid with excel export. My data is shown precisely as I want it and the grid works fine. However, the saveAsExcel function triggers the excelExport event, but no file is created. Same problem with the pdf export.
Here is my grid options:

```
grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        toolbar:["excel","pdf"],
        height: 500,
        scrollable: true,
        groupable: true,
        sortable: true,
        filterable: false,
        excel: {
            allPages:true,
            filterable:true
        },
        excelExport: function(e) {
            console.log('Firing Export');
            console.log(e.workbook);
            console.log(e.data);
        },
        pdfExport: function(e){
            console.log('PDF export');

        },
        columns: [
            { field: "date", title: "Time", template: "#= kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(date), 'MM/dd/yyyy') #", width: '120px'},
            { field: "customer", title: "Customer" },
            { field: "amount", title: "Total", format: "{0:c}", width: '70px', aggregates: ["sum"]},
            { field: "paid_with", title: "Payment", width: '130px'},
            { field: "source", title: "Source" },
            { field: "sale_location", title: "Sale Location" }
        ]
    }).data("kendoGrid");
```

This ajax is called whenever the search parameters for the data is changed. Where I refresh the datasource.

```
        $.ajax({
            'url':'/POS/ajax/loadTransactionsDetailsForDay.php',
            'data':{
                filters
            },
            'type':'GET',
            'dataType':'json',
            'success':function(response) {
                var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                    data: response.data.invoices,
                    pageSize: 100000,
                    schema: {
                        model: {
                            fields: {
                                date: {type: "string"},
                                customer: { type: "string" },
                                amount: { type: "number" },
                                paid_with: {type: "string"},
                                source: {type:"string"},
                                sale_location: {type:"string" }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
                grid.setDataSource(dataSource);
                grid.refresh();
            }

        });
```

The output from my console log is.

```
Firing Export.
```

A worksheet object.

```
Object {sheets: Array[1]}sheets: Array[1]0: Objectlength: 1__proto__: Array[0]__proto__: Object
```

and and array with these objects for every row in the grid:

```
0: o
   _events: Object
   _handlers: Object
   amount: 40.45
   customer: "customer 1"
   date: "2015-11-25T00:00:00-08:00"
   dirty: false
   employee: 23
   paid_with: "Check"
   parent: ()
   sale_location: "Main"
   source: "POS"
   uid: "70b2ba9c-15f7-4ac3-bea5-f1f2e3c800d3"
```

I have the latest version of kendo, I am loading jszip. I am running it on the latest version of chrome.
I have tried all kinds of variations of this code I can think of, including removing my schema, initializing the kendo anew every time in the callback.

Anyone got any idea why this would not work?

Every example on this I can find make it look super simple, just create the grid and call export... So I have to have overlooked something.

I am grateful for any ideas about this.

Thanks.

Comment: Your implementation seems ok.  Are you sure jszip is loaded before kendo?

Comment: I copied your javascript and it works fine (with an empty file). Could this be a problem with permissions? My files are written to my downloads folder.

Comment: @The_Black_Smurf Yes, it is loaded before.

I had a time limit so I ended up writing a CSV export of the grid instead. But will get back to this and try to find out what caused it.

Comment: @Fruitbat I could generate other files not through Kendo. So I do not think it is a permission error.

Answer (score 1):

It could be because the filename is missing.

Here the part with the filename added:

```
excel: {
        allPages:true,
        filterable:true,
        fileName: "Kendo UI Grid Export.xlsx"
    },
```

You can take a look here : [Grid Excel Export](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/excel-export)

And here for the pdf: [Grid Pdf Export](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/pdf-export)

Answer (score 0):

I have some following suggestion.

1. Can you add kendo deflate pako script file into your code and try.
2. Then remove the pdf export event and just try to export a pdf with toolbar  default functionality..check whether its working or not.
3. try to add a data-source ajax call with in a grid option using kendo-transport technique with read method.  http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-transport